# Faraday Effect, Satellites, and Electromagnetic Atmosphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, induction

If I launched a Satellite into orbit and dropped a silver wire caged in carbon fiber with aerodynamic wings (for support), would the Faraday effect of the wire traveling through earth's electromagnetic atmosphere (as the satellite orbits earth) generate a lot of electricity?

Also, would the wire being in the atmosphere eventually pull the satellite back down to earth?

Comment: @BrandonEnright This link in that question is just what I was looking for! http://www-istp.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/wtether.html

Comment: Your question was about dragging a wire through the upper atmosphere rather than just through Earth's magnetic field.  Does that other question actually answer your question?  If so we should mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Isn't earth's magnetic field avaliable in the upper-atmoshpere? Anyways, I don't know how to mark this as a duplicate, I might not have unlocked that ability yet with such low reputation.

Comment: Indeed the Earth's magnetic field is available well beyond the atmosphere of the Earth.  It sounded like your question was about generating electricity from the charged particles in the ionosphere, not from the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Ah! No, I'm talking about dragging a wire through the magnetic field (to induce the faraday effect)

Comment: Related: [Satellite power](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1121/8563).